# Update UIImageView with didset function

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I created a page structure using Scrollview. I update the paragraphText and HeaderText with didset, but I can't update the image. What do I need to do to update the image? Everything works except the image right now.

```
class PageView: UIView {

    var headerText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            headerTextField.text = headerText
        }
    }

    var paragraphText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            paragraphTextView.text = paragraphText
        }
    }

    private var cellImage = UIImageView()
     var imagee: UIImage? {
        didSet {
           cellImage.image = imagee
        }
    }

class PageController: UIViewController {

    let placeHolderText = "........"

    let placeHolderText1 = "......"
    var cellImage = UIImage(named: "asdasd")
    var cellImageLogin = UIImage(named: "asdasdff")

 let pageView1 = PageView(headerText: "123123", paragraphText: placeHolderText, backgroundColor: .red, image: cellImage! )
        views.append(pageView1)
 let pageView2 = PageView(headerText: "123213123", paragraphText: placeHolderText1, backgroundColor: .orange, image: cellImageLogin!)
        views.append(pageView2)
```

Comment: Have you tried by setting frame to image?

Comment: Can you show the code as an example?

Comment: Can you share any demo project?

Comment: https://dosya.co/a5lkerimegx1/PageController.swift.html
https://dosya.co/auovvuybgtt4/PageView.swift.html

Comment: I tried your field with my project but its giving an weird error. By any chance can you share working demo project?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the project right now. No error only the update process of cellimage does not occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `cellImage` don't have `frame` it won't be visible in your `PageView`

You need to add `frame` with for example

```
cellImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
```

in your `setup` method before `self.addSubview(cellImage)`

Also you need to apply the correct constraints as per your requirement.